# Parse List of Lists Into List of Dictionary (Using Dict Function)

Tags: python, list, dictionary, nested-lists

I am new in learning Python and having trouble parsing my list of list into list of dictionary, I can combine only the individual list into dictionary, but can not do so for the list of lists. Basically I have below data:

```
mylist = [[john, type A, 40], [Barbara, type O, 22]]
```

I have made def function to map the list into my dictionary key, but only for individual list:

```
dict_key = {'name': John, 'blood type': type O, 'Barbara': 8600}
```

What I am trying to do is to iterate all the records in mylist and parse each list and turn it into list of dictionary. So the end result would look like this:

```
list_dict = [{'name': John, 'blood type': type O, 'age': 40}, {'name': Barbara, 'blood type': type O, 'age': 22}]
```

Any help would be highly appreciated, have been stuck on this for so long! Thank you.

Comment: Show your function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
In [85]: mylist = [['john', 'type A', 40], ['Barbara', 'type O', 22]]                                                                                                                                                                                                         

In [86]: headers = ['name', 'blood type', 'age']                                                                                                                                                                                                                              

In [87]: answer = []                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          

In [88]: for record in mylist: 
    ...:     d = {} 
    ...:     for header,value in zip(headers, record): 
    ...:         d[header] = value 
    ...:     answer.append(d) 
    ...:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      

In [89]: answer                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
Out[89]: 
[{'name': 'john', 'blood type': 'type A', 'age': 40},
 {'name': 'Barbara', 'blood type': 'type O', 'age': 22}]
```

Of course, there's a one-liner for this:

```
In [90]: [dict(zip(headers, record)) for record in mylist]                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
Out[90]: 
[{'name': 'john', 'blood type': 'type A', 'age': 40},
 {'name': 'Barbara', 'blood type': 'type O', 'age': 22}]
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I just tried it, very elegant solution. Pretty embarrassed I've been trying for a while and still couldn't get an answer on my own, but anyway thanks!

Comment: @Esar: don't beat yourself up. This is the learning process. You're new; I've been doing this for over 10 years. Keep at it, and you'll definitely get there

Comment: Thank you for the kind words, will keep trying :)

Answer (score 0):

Let's try list and inner dict comprehension:

```
list_dict = [{x:y for x,y in zip(r,['name', 'blood type', 'age'])} for r in mylist]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mylist = [['john', 'type A', 40],['Barbara', 'type O', 22]]
keys=['name','blood type','age']
lst=[]
for i in mylist:
    d={}
    for n in range(3):
        d[keys[n]] = i[n]
    lst.append(d)
print(lst)
```